# Cannot find configure.ac file in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Where can I find the configure.ac file of ffmpeg?. I downloaded the latest version of ffmpeg from git, but couldn't find the configure.ac ( input for autoconf ).

I am in the process of adding a new proprietary media encoding/decoding in ffmpeg.  I plan to enable it via --enable-mylib ( like libfaac ). Hence the question.

Comment: FFmpeg doesn't use `autoconf`. See the `configure` file.

Comment: That means I need to edit the configure directly if I want to additional options for configure?

Answer (score 0):

As
[can be seen](http://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/e5858fe),
current source of FFmpeg does not use a `configure.ac` file, but simply the compiled `configure` file. You should be able to use options with the configure file

```
./configure --enable-libfaac
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/852c045/install-ffmpeg.sh)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My aim not to build using 'configure' script.  I want to edit 'configure' script to add support for a new media codec.  Normally configure script is generated by autoconf (which takes input as configure.ac) and we don't edit by hand.  Just curious how it is done for ffmpeg as I don't see configure.ac

Comment: @Sudheesh Not everything uses `autoconf`. I suggest you clone the FFmpeg repository with `git`, create a new branch, and start experimenting. View the source code for examples of how other external libraries are enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I have already done this. I added a new codec in ffmpeg and tested also. Everything seems to be OK.  But presently I have simply replaced one of the existing codec with mine to simplify the whole process. Now I want to do it in the proper way, so that I can contribute the changes back. I started going through the configure script. Now the only question is should I manually edit the 'configure' script?

Comment: @Sudheesh are you certain this is a new codec? FFmpeg already supports at least 370 codecs.

Comment: This is a different implementation of an existing codec. ffmpeg community may or may not approve this codec and that is a different discussion. My question is more towards configure script.